# Unable to load Cassandra table using a spark session, sparklyr and R

Tags: r, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, sparklyr

I am using Spark 2.1.0 and trying to connect a Cassandra cluster. I have used the latest sparklyr. I have set the default configurations as below  
default:

```
  # local-only configuration
  sparklyr.cores.local: !expr parallel::detectCores()
  spark.sql.shuffle.partitions.local: !expr parallel::detectCores()

  # cassandra settings
spark.cassandra.connection.host:<Cassandra IP>
spark.cassandra.auth.username: <uid>
spark.cassandra.auth.password:<pass>

sparklyr.defaultPackages:
- com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0
- com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-RC1
- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.1.4
```

The jars are located in the root directory where the source files are located.

I have performed the following actions. Everything went fine until I tried to invoke the read function. I have set the jar location explicitly.

```
   > library(sparklyr)
    > config <- spark_config()
    Warning message:
    In readLines(input, encoding = "UTF-8") :
      incomplete final line found on '/home/bsc/BSCAnalytics/config.yml'
    > config[["sparklyr.jars.default"]] <- c("/home/bsc/BSCAnalytics/cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar")
    > 
    > sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.1.0")
    Warning message:
    In readLines(input, encoding = "UTF-8") :
      incomplete final line found on '/home/bsc/BSCAnalytics/config.yml'
    > Spark.session <- sparklyr::invoke_static(sc, "org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession", "builder") %>% sparklyr::invoke("config", "spark.cassandra.connection.host", "<Cassandra IP>") %>% sparklyr::invoke("getOrCreate")
```

when I try to invoke the read function, the run-time is not able to find the jars. I witness the following error:

```
> event_df <- invoke(Spark.session, "read") %>% invoke("format", "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") %>% invoke("option", "keyspace", "kps") %>% invoke("option", "table", "tab_event") %>% invoke("load")
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:94)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:89)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:55)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:49)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(DataSource.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(DataSource.scala:554)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25.apply(DataSource.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25.apply(DataSource.scala:554)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:554)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
library(sparklyr)

config <- spark_config()
config[["sparklyr.defaultPackages"]] <- c(
   "datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-RC1-s_2.11")

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "1.6.1", config = config)

df <- sparklyr:::spark_data_read_generic(
  sc,
  "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra",
  "format", list(
    keyspace = "dev",
    table = "emp"
)) %>% invoke("load")

cassandra_tbl <- sparklyr:::spark_partition_register_df(
  sc,
  df,
  name = "emp",
  repartition = 0,
  memory = FALSE)

cassandra_tbl
```

See also https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/520

Comment: Hi Javier,
Thanks.  I would like to share following details for your perusal and seek your recommendations:

Our Spark(2.1) Clusters are not co located with Cassandra(3.x) nodes
Cassandra is secured with user ID and Password


Please let me know the following:

Where do I place the Spark Cassandra connector jar and, how would Sparlyr refer to it? It seems you are passing the maven attributes to the function setting up the config parameter
Where do we pass the cluster IPs, user Id and Password?
How do we load frozen or any other Cassandra complex objects in a DF for further analysis?

Comment: @SCB did you get any solution to connect to remote Cassandra using sparklyr?

Comment: @JavierLuraschi could you please tell me how to connect to remote Cassandra  using sparklyr?